# .Net Core IDataProtector vs. Always Encrypted for sensitive db columns?

Tags: database, encryption, data-protection

I am going to store sensitive data like SSN and bank account numbers in my SQL Server database.  The database is located on a server separate from where the application code is run, and I have Security Groups set up to only allow inbound access to the db server from my app server IP.  I have already implemented the IDataProtector API and am using it to store encrypted passwords in my db, so I was going to use this to store the SSN and bank info as well.

But I read about Always Encrypted today, which is a SQL Server-based method you can use to encrypt specific columns.  From the Microsoft page:  *"Always Encrypted allows clients to encrypt sensitive data inside client applications and never reveal the encryption keys to the Database Engine (SQL Database or SQL Server). As a result, Always Encrypted provides a separation between those who own the data and can view it, and those who manage the data but should have no access."*

If I'm mostly concerned with hackers getting into my db and stealing data, which one of these methods is more secure?  The master key for Always Encrypted would be stored in the Windows Certificate Store on the app server.  I honestly don't know where the keys for IDataProtection are stored since it's been awhile since I set it up. I don't have anything explicit in Startup in services.AddDataProtection().

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I think I'll go with Data Protector for now.  The main decision point was that I don't want to use Azure Key Vault for centralized key storage, and Always Encrypted does not offer many alternatives.

I found that I can't use Windows Certificate Store for the column master keys because my EC2 instances are on a load balancer/auto-scaler, and so the Windows environment could be rebuilt at any time and lose the keys.